# Creating a PHP Function to Search a .TXT for a Specific Username and Password

Tags: php, loops, authentication

So, I am trying to create a login form as an example so there is no encryption or anything too confusing, it has 3 files, a *loginform.php*, *logindisplay.php*, and a *password.txt*. The goal of this question is to tell me why the function below doesn't work and what I can do to fix it.

The function is meant to open up the *password.txt* file and search for a username and password, which would be on separate lines *username **over** the password*, and if the file doesn't have it, it is supposed to tell them to add it using a specific button (which the creation of that data to *password.txt* already works perfectly in the code) otherwise allow the login to be successful. Any help would be great and please keep in mind I know *very little* about PHP, so the code may need to be explained a bit depending! Thank you and sorry if this is a bad question!

Also $isLogin is supposed to be a global variable, and is already in the code!

```
function searchPasswordFile($UserName, $PassWord){
   $search = $UserName. "\n" .$PassWord. "\n";
   $lines = file('password.txt');
   $found = false;
   foreach($lines as $line) {
     if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
       $isLogin = true;
       echo "Thank you for logging in!";
     }
   }
     if(!$found) {
       echo "No login found, please Create a new Login!<br />\n";
     }

   $islogin = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `file()` to read your `password.txt` file but then you want to search for **multi-line** content. That's will never match because your `$lines` holds each read line separately. You need to either drop using `\n` as separator (If your username can't contain say `:` or `|` that would be a good candidate)  or rework how you read that file.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is best to have the user name and password on the same line & separated by a single space (such as password.txt below)

```
UserName1 PassWord1
UserName2 PassWord2
UserNameN PassWordN
```

this would simplify comparing the string input with a user name and password

```
$search = $UserName." ".$PassWord;
```

to lines of password.txt

So here goes the proposed updated code:

```
<?php
function searchPasswordFile($UserName, $PassWord){
  $search = $UserName." ".$PassWord;             # Proposed change here
  $lines = file('password.txt');
  $found = false;
  foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
      $isLogin = true;
      echo "Thank you for logging in!";
    }
  }
    if(!$found) {
      echo "No login found, please Create a new Login!<br />\n";
    }

  $islogin = false;
}

echo searchPasswordFile("UserName2", "PassWord2");
```

Output:

```
Thank you for logging in!
```

'hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**password.txt**

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

**password.php**

```
<?php
  
// set $isLogin to the return value from searchPasswordFile
$isLogin = searchPasswordFile('three','four');

function searchPasswordFile($UserName, $PassWord){
        // read password.txt into $lines as an array
        $lines = file('password.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

        // get the number of lines in the array
        $lineCount = count($lines);

        // loop through the array, advancing the index by two each time
        for ($i = 0; $i < $lineCount; $i += 2) {
                // if there is a match
                if($lines[$i] === $UserName && $lines[$i+1] === $PassWord) {
                        // report success and return
                        echo "Thank you for logging in!".PHP_EOL;
                        return true;
                }
        }
        // report failure and return
        echo "No login found, please Create a new Login!".PHP_EOL;
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file with [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file) you are getting an array where *each element is a separate line*. You are searching for two lines, but only across a line at a time.

There are many different(and better) ways to do this, but here is an option based on your existing approach.

```php
$lineCount=count($lines);
for($l=0;$l<$lineCount;$l+=2){
    if(rtrim($lines[$l])==$UserName&&rtrim($lines[$l+1])==$PassWord){
        //Credentials matched
    }
}
```

Ultimately, there are many issues here. First, *never* store plaintext passwords. Look into hashing. PHP has built-in functions to help with this. Second, when comparing passwords, you must be mindful of various vulnerabilities(for instance, timing attacks, which are not mitigated in my example). Your original example(had it worked) would also have allowed authenticating using one user's password as the username and the next user's username as the password. There are plenty of standard file formats with built-in support in PHP that would be easier and safer to parse(JSON or XML for instance are supported in core PHP). You should really reconsider this approach if you are building anything remotely serious. Authentication is not a place to take shortcuts.